# Codeigniter session work fine on local but not working on Godaddy

Tags: codeigniter

I developed website on php framework (Codeigniter) that working fine on my local (WAMP Server). When I upload it to Godaddy hosting, it unable to login into website.  Below is the login class function.

```
public function index()
{

    if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') == 1)
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/dashboard', 'refresh');


     $this->load->view('backend/login');
}


function ajax()
{
    $response = array();


    $email      = $_POST["email"];
    $password   = $_POST["password"];
    $response['submitted_data'] = $_POST;       


    $login_status = $this->validate_login( $email ,  sha1($password) );
    $response['login_status'] = $login_status;
    if ($login_status == 'success') {
        $response['redirect_url'] = '';
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}


function validate_login($email  =   '' , $password   =  '')
{
    $credential =   array(  'email' => $email , 'password' => $password );

    $query = $this->db->get_where('users' , $credential);

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->row();
          $this->session->set_userdata('admin_login', '1');
          $this->session->set_userdata('admin_id', $row->id);
          $this->session->set_userdata('name', $row->name);
          $this->session->set_userdata('login_type', 'admin');

          return 'success';
    }

    return 'invalid';
}
```

I realize that $this->session->set_userdata() method is not working on godaddy.

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: May I ask what is the setting for '$config['sess_use_database']' in your `/application/config/config.php` file?

Answer (score 2):

```
Please try this 
Please add  session library  just like below.

$this->load->library('session');
if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') == 1)
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/dashboard', 'refresh');



     $this->load->view('backend/login');
```

Comment: As I already mentioned that my application working fine on my local machine. As I already load session library in autoload.php i-e $autoload['libraries'] = array('session')

Comment: I also try by adding $this->load->library('session') on remote server. and it fail.

Answer (score 2):

First Load Session Library
then 
Instead of Using this

```
  if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') == 1)
```

Use This

```
if ($this->session->userdata['admin_login'] == 1)
```

Check if it is working or not

Comment: Still getting same error.

Comment: There is no issue in coding but problem in godaddy hosting, it could not store sessions on hosting server.

Comment: write if ($this->session->userdata['admin_login'] == '1'){redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/dashboard', 'refresh');}else{$this->load->view('backend/login');}

Comment: dear
the code 
if($this->session->userdata('admin_login') == 1)
is working fine. I deeply checked that code i-e
if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') == 1)
 echo "session set";
else
 echo "session not set";

so when i run this it print "session not set"

the problem is in godaddy hosting.

Comment: this will not be an hosting problem ? what error you are getting ?

Answer (score 1):

Try a few alternatives may work:
Change these lines in `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'cisession';     //remove(underscore)
$config['cookie_domain']    = ".example.com";  //make it site wide valid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store multiple session variable in array

```
function validate_login($email = '', $password = '') {
    $credential = array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password);

    $query = $this->db->get_where('users', $credential);

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->row();
        $sess_array = array(
                'admin_login' => 1,
                'admin_id' => $row->id,
                'name', $row->name,
                'login_type', 'admin'
            );  

        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
    }
    return 'invalid';
}
```

You need to upload `session library` in your constructor

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct(); /* necessary! */

    /* load model for calls to database */
    $this->load->library('session');// load session library
    $this->load->helper('url');
}
```

In your `index`  you have to check user `logged_in` is set or not

```
public function index()
{
        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){// check session set or not
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/dashboard', 'refresh');
        $this->load->view('backend/login');
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, i assume you're using CI2, as you're getting FALSE on a non-existing session var. CI sessions use cookies and / or a database, depending on your config. what are the cookie settings on your config file?

you should pay attention to these settings:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

and these ones (default config shown on both cases):

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

is your site hosted on a subdomain? cookies are set via headers. is there any output being generated before your cookies are set? set up your log_threshold to 2 so you can see eventual errors and debug messages being generated.

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 2;
```

did you set up an encription key?

```
$config['encryption_key'] = '[there-must-be-something-here]';
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all answers that mention here, but not work for my issue.

My issue is

> `$this->session->userdata('admin_login')` returns false.

Finaly I tried database to store session.

```
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
```

And created **ci_sessions** table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

Then it works fine

Answer (score 0):

This should be Your Config Configuration

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200; 
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Also In your Model You must set the session.

```
public function login ()
{
    $user = $this->get_by(array(
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'password' => $this->hash($this->input->post('password')),

    ), TRUE);

    if (count($user)) {
        // Log in user
        $data = array(
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'gender'=>$user->gender,
            'user_num'=>$user->user_num,    
            'id' => $user->id,
            'loggedin' => TRUE,
            'balance' =>$user->balance,
            'usertype' =>'admin',
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    }
}
```

this Works for me :)